# AFTER INSERT trigger on same table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with 4 columns:

```
ID, start_time, time, end_time
```

Now if I want to insert rows into my table then end_time should be filled automatically. So I only have to supply two values (ID is inserted automatically): start_time and time.

To do that I use DATE_ADD function.

```
date_add(start_time, interval time minute)
```

I want to use AFTER INSERT trigger to do that, but I don't know how to create that trigger.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: DATE_ADD

Comment: And what would you enter for `end_time` ?

Comment: I would enter date_add function. I edited that a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not update the same table where the trigger is being executed.
So you need to use `before insert`

```
delimiter //
create trigger table_before_insert before insert on table_name
for each row
begin
 set new.end_time = date_add(/*your increment logic here */);
end;//

delimiter;
```

you can access all the values using `new` and use them inside the date_add function as needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the proper datatypes (`DATETIME` / `TIME`), you can do the `DATE_ADD` in the query directly as well. For example, if you'd want to set the `end_time` to be `start_time + time`, you could do this in your insert statment:

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`start_time`, `time`, `end_time`)
VALUES (
    '2015-04-22 13:37:00',
    '02:30:00',
    DATE_ADD(`start_time`, INTERVAL `time` HOUR_SECOND)
);
```

That would set `end_time` to `2015-04-22 16:07:00` instantly.